# Issue with Firefox in protractor/selenium tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, firefox, protractor

I'm pretty new to using Protractor and Selenium so bear with me, I've set up the protractor conf.js and spec.js files which work using Chrome/IE11/EDGE asynchronously using the multi-capabilities option in conf.js. But when Firefox attempts to load it hits an "The address isn't valid" page on the browser, so I assume it's not the Firefox webdriver. The errors I receive in the console are ;

```
[12:41:30] I/testLogger - [firefox #21] PID: 12532
[firefox #21] Specs: d:\My Documents\Visual Studio2015\Projects\TaskManager\FrontNodeTests\Tests\spec.js
[firefox #21]
[firefox #21] [12:40:43] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
[firefox #21]
[firefox #21] C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27
[firefox #21]     super(opt_error);
[firefox #21]     ^
[firefox #21] WebDriverError: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.
[12:41:30] I/launcher - firefox #21 failed with exit code: 1
[12:41:30] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

My conf.js file is;

```
exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine2',
seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
specs: ['spec.js'],
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    }, {
        'browserName': 'internet explorer',
        'platform': 'ANY',
        'version': '11'
    },
    {
        'browserName': 'firefox'
    },
    {
        'browserName' : 'MicrosoftEdge'
    }
],
onPrepare: function () {
    var specReporter = require("jasmine-spec-reporter");
    jasmine.getEnv()
        .addReporter(
        new specReporter(
            {
                displayStackTrace: 'all',
                displaySuccessesSummary: true,
                displayPendingSpec: true,
                displaySuiteNumber: true
            }));
},
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:'
};
```

I'm also using .bat files to run the Selenium server, and Protractor test suites if that's any assistance.

Any help/advice would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Do you really have the `http://localhost:` base URL configured?

Comment: I have my angular web app to run on a localhost, I just have that there so I can prefix my web requests.